# How to turn on snippet preview in adjacent window using vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can't find a setting to show description on the right side. Default user settings on MacOS.
[image: What I'm looking for]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toggleSuggestionDetails` command gives details (if you won't hide it, details will appear every time). Default keybinding for this command on Mac is `ctrl+space`, which prevents to expand a widget (cause language changing uses the same keybinding). I just chose other keys to show more without changing user settings (but added `"editor.suggest.showStatusBar": true` since it seemed useful to me).[image]